# Toggle Through Multiple Classes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggleclass

I am attempting to cycle through 3 classes when the user clicks a button.  I found someone with the [same challenge as me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894250/toggle-between-3-classes-using-toggleclass), but I lack the reputation to comment on the post for any follow up.

Here is the original code to cycle through the classes:

```
$('.one, .two, .three').click(function() {                             
    this.className = {
       three : 'one', one: 'two', two: 'three'
    }[this.className];
});
```

and I have modified it as follows:

```
$('#next').click(function() {                             
    this.className = {
       liscombe : 'digby', digby: 'keltic', keltic: 'liscombe'
    }[this.className];
});
```

This works as expected and cycles through the classes on the #next element, however I would like to have the class change happen on the body tag when the #next is clicked.  I'm not sure how to modify the 'this.' I have tried body.className but that did not work.

How can this be modified to have the body class change on click?

Comment: have you tried $('body').className?

Comment: I did try that but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.body.className` should work

Comment: Boom!  That is it.  I had given up at body.className and didn't think of document.body.className.

Answer (score 0):

'this' is just passing whatever selector you used in the initial selection. So its passing #next. Change "this" to $('body')